# NextJS Routing - Como executar um evento após o push de uma nova rota?

Tags: react, next.js

Tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida em NextJS que exibe produtos (componente SearchResults), e tenho uma coluna com filtros para otimizar esta busca (componente Aside). Pra cada vez que altero um filtro, a função *handleChange* é executada.

Essa função tem como objetivo:

- Ativar a prop `loading` de SearchResults = true (para eu mostrar um loader de carregamento). Essa prop recebe o estado atual de isOnDemandLoading.
- Capturar os filtros ativos;
- Montar uma nova URL e dar um router.push pra executá-la;

Tudo isso está funcionando, porém, após executar o router.push, o estado de isOnDemandLoading continua true. Gostaria que ele fosse false ao entrar essa nova rota.

**Info que talvez seja importante: Estou usando a ContextAPI pra poder guardar esses states para utilizar em vários componentes. Mas tentei também direto com useState.**

Abaixo, segue meu componente "resumido", e logo abaixo dele, vou mostrar minhas tentativas:

```
export default function Products(props){

    const { isOnDemandLoading, setIsOnDemandLoading } = useAppContext();

    setIsOnDemandLoading(false); // * ESTE SE DEIXO AQUI, GERA O ERRO AO TENTAR RESETAR O STATE

    const router = useRouter();

    // * Esta função executo quando há uma mudança nos filtros. Ela que gera o push no router
    function handleChange(options){

        // * Seto como TRUE o state de loading
        setIsOnDemandLoading(true);

        // * E dou o push
        router.push({
            pathname: '/products',
            query: {
                params
            }
        });
    }

    return (
        <main>
            <Aside handleChange={handleChange}/>
            <SearchResults loading={isOnDemandLoading} />
        </main>
    )
}
```

**Tentativa 01: Alterar o state logo no inicio do componente**

Reparem que na linha 5, eu tenho um setIsOnDemandLoading(false). Esta foi uma das minhas ideias, e ao executá-la, é gerado um erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tentativa 02: componentDidUpdate**

Pensei em executar esse hook dentro da função, mas ele simplesmente dá syntax error e não consigo fazer como a documentação propõe, no meu caso. Talvez eu não esteja fazendo certo.

**Tentativa 03: Ouvir o evento routeChangeComplete**

Esta é a que acho mais promissora.
Mas, quando coloco no código, ele diz que events.on é undefined.

```
router.push({
    pathname: '/products',
    query: {
        params
    }
}).events.on('routeChangeComplete', setIsOnDemandLoading(false));
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tentativa 04: evento routeChangeComplete dentro useEffect**

Logo abaixo do const router, eu adiciono o seguinte listener:

```
useEffect(() => {

    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', setIsOnDemandLoading(false));

    return () => {
        router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', setIsOnDemandLoading(false))
    }
}, [router]);
```

Porém, quando ele carrega a nova rota, ele dá o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma saída para meu caso, sem que eu tenha que refatorar meu sistema de busca?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', setIsOnDemandLoading(false))
    }
}, [router]);
```

Através desta diretriz, ao fazer o npm build, ele funciona.
Acho que poderia ser uma instabilidade do npm run dev. Uma vez que abri hoje, o erro não aconteceu usando desta maneira acima, e em produção com o build feito, têm funcionado.

Answer (score -1):

Olá.

Adicionar o useEffect no componente que é montado da rota acionada, setando, pela api de contexto, `setIsOnDemandLoading(false)` não resolveria o problema?

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Não entendi. Colocar o useEffect lá onde eu crio minha api de contexto? Não faz muito sentido, uma vez que o gerenciador das rotas está neste meu componente acima.